# Assign GitHub issue to more than 1 people

Tags: github

I was able to do it, Now, I cant anymore.

I have this message: `Assign up to 1 person to this issue`. If I select somebody else, `alan345` will be removed

[image]

Is it a premium feature now?

Comment: are you the owner of repo?

Comment: yes I am.. I sent a message to github..

Comment: Same problem here, on some issues I'm able to add multiple assignees and on some other issues only 1 can exist. The only way I found to resolve this is to delete the issue and re-open a new one.

Comment: The documentation [says](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/assigning-issues-and-pull-requests-to-other-github-users): "...Private repositories on the free plan are limited to one person per issue or pull request..."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Answer from Github:

With the recent updates, if you are using GitHub Free, then you will only be able to have a single assignee for issues or pull requests:

https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/faq-about-changes-to-githubs-plans#if-i-downgrade-from-github-team-or-a-legacy-plan-to-github-free-what-features-will-i-lose

Comment: Thanks!


But... now what really want is the opposite: the ability to limit all issues in my GitHub org to ≤1 assignee: the [directly responsible individual](https://fleetdm.com/handbook/company/why-this-way#why-direct-responsibility) for completing the next steps in the work

Answer (score 2):

As per the docs [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/assigning-issues-and-pull-requests-to-other-github-users) for github.com, you still should be able to do it. I just checked on my android app and I am able to do it.

I have just verified in Web as well and I am able to assign to multiple people. I am also seeing the message "Assign up to 10 people to this issue".

Comment: do you see the message `Assign up to 1 person to this issue`?

Comment: I have updated my answer.  I am able to see "Assign up to 10 people to this issue".

Comment: "...Private repositories on the free plan are limited to one person per issue or pull request..."